# Bluetooth gamepad Pro controller and Ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, gamepad

I get a gamepad Nitendo Switch (compatible) in bluetooth
I am able to connect it to Ubuntu 20.04 with bluetooth.
he is recognized as gamepad as "Pro Controller"

But none of the calibration tools for gamepad detect it ?

- antimicro
- sdl gamepad controler
- jstest-gtk

Anyidea to help ubuntu to tell to game or gamepad calibration tools to know it?

(I try to plug it with usb cable but lsusb did not see anythings...)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I try to pass to Ubuntu 20.10 but it does not change...
So I add a bluetooth dongle... and it works fine.
But it's not the simple way....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1119128)

Comment: As the "answer" comme from the author, it was not a critique or request clarification :-). It was a way to tell that I found an other way (not fully satisfying) to work...